# How can I limit the number of characters that can be copied/pasted?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I'm looking to write a script that stops me from copying and pasting anything under a certain character count - or barring that, a way to disable copy/paste on a per application basis.

This is because I have noticed I have become lazy and I think it probably affects my memory - or at least it isn't helping it get better! I have scoured Google with dozens of search terms - and looked all over SO/SU to no avail.

Where would I start looking to achieve something like this? Even just terms to help my hunt would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty weird requirement… all I can think of right now is taking an open source clipboard manager [like Flycut](https://github.com/TermiT/flycut) and modifying the source in such a way that it does not copy (or removes) anything under a certain character count.

Comment: It sure is a weird requirement! Hence there being next to nothing related to it [that I can find] on the net. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Out of interest can you see my reasoning even though it's a weird request? If i was forced to remember and retype anything say over 100 chars I would have thought it would help train my brain to remember passages of text better - or at least stop it from getting any worse :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the source code from [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jumpcut/) program and modify it to alert you whenever you copy text that is fewer than the number of characters you desire. It should be a simple matter of measuring the byte count of the latest entry again a predefined byte count.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link. That will be a great starting point. I actually hadn't thought of looking for an open source tool that may already exist. Thanks! :D

Also thanks to @slhck who suggested something similar :)